# Volume of a bounded region $S$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Any help is appreciated!

Determine the volume of the bounded region $S$ enclosed by the surface $z = 1 - x^2 -y^2$ and the plane $z = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**:$ V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} (1-r^2)rdrd\theta $

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Integrate the function $f(x,y)=1-x^2-y^2$ over the disc $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ (where the graph of $f$ stays over the $z=0$ plane, i. e. $z=f(x,y)\geq 0$):
$$|S|=\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq 1}(1-x^2-y^2)\,dxdy.$$
It will be helpful to use polar coordinates.